# How do I manually end the session in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Let's say I'm building a self-service ticket terminal app to be used at a train station (web app). I would like to use Google Analytics to track user behavior.

The problem is that it will be a single device which would have many people using it. For this reason Google Analytics reports won't accurately reflect the number of users. To resolve this, I had an idea to reset GA session each time user finishes a transaction.

It appears Universal Analytics supported this via the [sessionControl](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#sc) property. However, I was unable to find an alternative in GA4.

I tried emitting [`session_start` event](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069#session_start) manually and the event does show up in dashboard. However, looks like it doesn't affect internal gtag state, meaning all consecutive events are still associated with the previous session. This means "session count" and "engaged sessions count" is still incorrect in GA dash.

The question is: is it possible to manually end the session in GA4? If not, are there any alternatives I could look into for my use case?

Comment: If it's a web app. So is it connected through browser? You can just clear all the cookie that are related from google-analyitcs. It should reset session and determine here is the new user and session if the cookie is gone.

Comment: I tried this approach as well. The problem is that it's a single page app so even if I remove the cookie the session doesn't reset unless I reload the page. Looks like gtag refers to its internal state and not the cookie for session ID.

Comment: Don't have similar working environment. But maybe try to call gtag config again after the reseting cookie. From document there is no way like reset in gtag.